# Database fields that automatically update on creation or on update with symfony

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, field

For example (it is a bad example for the purpose of my question), i want to store the user fullname by concatenating the firstname and lastname.
I have a table user with firstname, lastname, fullname

Is there a way to create a field in the schema with a trigger function that stores in fullname firstname+lastname ? The same way the created_at works (with timestampable)

I use doctrine and symfony 1.4

Comment: One way could be to write my own doctrine behaviour.
it is explained here: http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/08-Advanced-Doctrine-Usage. But maybe there is a simpler solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definately don't need to create a behaviour for something as simple and as unreusable as this.

Just override your model save method:

```
class Model extends BaseModel
{
  public function save(Doctrine_Connection $conn)
  {
    $this->fullname = sprintf ('%s %s', $this->firstname, $this->lastname);
    return parent::save($conn);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd overwrite the setFirstName and setFullName methods so the new value is immediately available, but this works as well.

Comment: sprintf() is overkill for just concatenating strings when no formatting is needed.  Otherwise a good straightforward solution.

Answer (score 1):

Dziamid has already directly answered what you asked.  But consider also whether you really need to store such duplicate data.  A different solution which I use is this:

```
class Model extends BaseModel
{
  public function getFullName() {
    return ($this->name_first . ' ' . $this->name_last);
  }

  public function getFullNameLastFirst() {
    return ($this->name_last . ', ' . $this->name_first);
  }
}
```